# get before and after days based on 2 dataframes (date time )

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-cleaning

i have a data frame which is of format(date range from start="2018-09-09",end="2020-02-02") with values from 1 to 513

[image: df1]

I have another data frame with the format(only 3 dates)

[image: df2]

based on second data frame i want 2 dates before and 1 date after what I mean is this

[image: df3]

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Corrected answer as per the question

If you do this:

```
keep = []
for val in df2['value']:
    keep += [val-3, val-2, val-1, val]
df_final = df1.take(keep)
```

Assumption: Your `value` columns always starts from 1 and is sequential. Also, its datatype is integer not string.

**What it does:**
The row numbers (indices) of every date = `value` of that row - 1, since indices start from 0.
So this keeps only the `value-3` (2 days before), `value-2` (1 day before), `value-1` (that day present in df2) and `value` (1 day after) indices in the `keep` list.

Then `DataFrame.take(indices)` does the work for us, by only taking from the mentioned `DataFrame df1` the rows with indices mentioned in the argument `indices`, a list.

Comment: your code only works when the data frame length is 2 ,it doesn't answer my question

Comment: @sra There is no condition on the dataframes I used as an example to be any number of rows long. The code should work regardless of how many rows you have.
Here is a link to my example with 5 and 3 rows instead: 
[link](https://ibb.co/vkNK92j)

Comment: i understand you code, but my requirement is not that, for every date in df2 i need 3 days before  and 1 day based on df1 no more than that.

Comment: Okay, I understood your question better now, have a direction to go in and will post an edit to my answer

Comment: @sra i've edited my answer, i hope this works for you.